# $3x=6$ has one solution, but rewriting it as $3x^2=6x$ gives two solutions. Which is correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have some confusion with simple equation.

Say $3x = 6$. It simply gives $x=2$.

But it can also be written as $3x^2=6x$. Now we get two values of $x$ as $2$ and $0$.

Which one is correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Although $x=0$ satisfies the second equation, it doesn't satisfy the first, original equation.

Comment: and if you multiply that equation with $(x-1)$ you also get $x=1$ as a solution

Comment: You get $x=0$ **or** $x=2$.

Comment: $3x=6$ cannot be written as $3x^2=6x$ since the two of them are different.

Comment: $3x=6\implies3x^2=6x$, but $3x^2=6x\,\,\,\not\!\!\!\!\implies3x=6$. They are not equivalent, so the solutions are not the same.

Comment: When you multiplied the original equation by $x$, you introduced an [extraneous solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions).  Similar phenomenon if you square both sides:  $9x^2=36$ has $x=2$ and $-2$ as solutions

Answer (score 3):

Consider what happens if you multiply both sides of an equation by $0$. Let's say you start with
$$x = 3.$$
Multiplying by $0$,
$$0 = 0,$$
which is true for *all* values of $x$. You've lost information from the original equation, and you can't really trust this anymore, in a manner of speaking.

In your example, when you multiply both sides by $x$, notice that if $x=0$, you run into the same problem. As others have pointed out in the comments, you similarly have to be careful when you multiply by other expressions such as $x-1$, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was solving for f'(x)=3$x^2$ + 6x and when f'(x)=0 i.e 3$x^2$ + 6x = 0. So aren't 3$x^2$ + 6x = 0 and 3$x^2$ = -6x equivalent. Because the former can be written as 3x(x+2) = 0 and this gives x as 0 and -2. And the later can be written as 3x = -6 and this gives x = -2.If I go with the later,  I will miss x=0 .

Comment: @RajeshMarndi Yes, $3x^2+6x=0$ is equivalent to $3x^2=-6x$. But you are wrong to say that $3x^2=-6x$ can be written as $3x=-6$, for the same reason that you cannot write $x=3$ as $0=0$.

Comment: @RajeshMarndi I was writing my answer from the starting point of $x=3$, then multiplying; that was the implication in your question. But from your comments, you're starting with $3x^2+6x=0$, then dividing by $x$. The mistake is that if $x=0$, you've divided by $0$, which is forbidden. Always check this when you divide. A safer alternative is to factor: $3x(x+2)=0$, so either $x=0$ or $x=-2$.

Answer (score 1):

The fact depends upon what equation you are dealing with. In the first case, $3x=6$, you are dealing with a linear equation. So it will have at most $1$ solution which is $x=2$. Also, graphically, we have:

[image]

But, when you are dealing with $3x^2=6x$, which can be rewritten as $3x(x-2)=0$, you are actually dealing with two equations $3x=0$ and $x-2=0$. By introducing an x on both the sides, graphically, you are kinda bending the $y=3x$ graph to $y=3x^2$ and tilting the line $y=6$ to $y=6x$. So that would incorporate some extraneous roots.

[image]

Well, the answer to your question ,"3x=6 has one solution, but rewriting it as 3x2=6x gives two solutions. Which is correct?" - Both are correct. Just depends upon you that which equation are you looking to solve/deal with. The correctness of the answer also depends upon the context of the problem. But I hope the difference between the two is clear to you, both algebraically and graphically. :)